# using linq2Xml to edit element but with Xpath?

Tags: xpath, linq-to-xml

Im loading an xml from stream

```
       XDocument xmlFile = XDocument.Load(stream);
       var query = from c in xmlFile.Elements("//Band")    //error here
                   select c;

modify query....
```

Is it possible to find elements which are in format of Xpath ? (`//Band`) ?

p.s. I can use descendants but I want to ask about xpath....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use the [`Descendants()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb353813.aspx) method**:

```
from c in xmlFile.Descendants("Band")
  select c;
```

**Or if you want to specify true XPath expressions**, use the following Extensions:

- **[`XPathEvaluate()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341675.aspx)**
- **[`XPathSelectElement()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb351355.aspx)**
- **[`XPathSelectElements()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342176.aspx)**